# If $g$ is the inverse of function $f$ and $f'(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^n}$, Find $g'(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

I tried the question and got an answer by the following steps:

$f(g(x))=x$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t to $x$, we get

$f'(g(x)).g'(x)=1$

**And therefore,**

$g'(x)=1+\left[{g(x)} \right]^n$

**Now my question is, are there any alternate ways to approach this problem? Especially ones which may need some Integration?**

Comment: Well, you haven't finished, have you? $g'(x)=1+\left[{g(x)} \right]^n$ is not yet a solution.

Comment: OP did not specify if he needs an explicit answer. Wolfram alpha suggests that explicit answer involves inverse hypergeometric functions, so maybe it's better this way? :D

Comment: @Andreas oh? I thought that was an answer. 

Comment: could you maybe suggest a better/correct solution?

Comment: The answer depends on the question. It is for you to decide, whether you want to have an explicit or implicit expression for $g'(x)$ as the final solution. Perhaps you can clarify your question

Comment: Well the answer prescribed was the same as I had posted.. but there wasn't any solutions. And hence I came here searching for a solution involving Integration maybe (I'm addicted to it. :p )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original equation

$f'(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^n}$

Integrate it and define the result as $y$

$f(x)= \int \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx + C = y$

Invert $f(x)$ to get $g(y)$

$x = g(y)$

Differentiate w.r.t $y$, and use implicit differentiation to rewrite derivative via $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and compute it as a function of $x$. Then substitute $x = g(y)$.

$g'(y) = \frac{dx}{dy} = 1 / \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + x^n = 1 + g(y)^n$

Essentially both my and your approaches do the same thing. I could technically integrate to get the explicit formulation $y(x)$, and then inverted it to substitute $x(y)$, thus getting an explicit expression for $g(y)$, but it was not necessary for an explicit expression. You will always integrate at some point, either solving for $y(x)$, or when solving the last ODE for $g'(y)$

Comment: Thanks! But what exactly is the integral of $\frac{1}{1+x^n}$?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says it's a hypergeometric function. For arbitrary integer $n$, you will not get a nice answer it seems

Comment: Formins Got no clue what hypergeometric functions are.. Guess I'll learn it then! But thanks!!

Comment: They are complicated functions of 4 parameters, that have standard functions like $log(x)$ as special cases. I doubt that you will ever use them in your life, unless you really need an analytic solution.

Comment: oh thanks! Sounds like a lot of fun!